Unsure of appropriate transformation / link function in GAM
I am working with a response variable with kind of funny characteristics, and I am not sure of the appropriate transformation and/or link function for my model, based on the diagnostic plots I am getting with gam.check().
The response variable is Relative Thermal Resistance to Mixing (RTRM), a dimensionless index that can be used to quantify the extent of lake or pond stratification. RTRM is the difference in density between two layers of water ÷ the difference in density between water at 4ºC and 5ºC. This means it is a continuous variable with variance that increases with increasing values, but it is not technically bounded by zero, and its practical lower bound is slightly below zero (the lowest value in my data is approximately -.03). I am trying to figure out a model that determines this for a small pond, using weather variables.
Here is a time series and a histogram of the data I am working with, so you can get a better sense of how this variable is behaving.

I am not brand new to GAMs, but I am not particularly experienced with them, either, so any advice on this would be appreciated.
Here is the model formula I am using. The independent variables are temperature, wind direction (circular), and wind speed (only included for its interaction with wind direction), all on a one-day lag relative to RTRM:
Weather.limno%>%
  gam(daily.rtrm~  s(temp.lag1)+
        ti(wind.dir.lag1, bs = "cc")+ 
        ti(wind.dir.lag1,wind.sp.lag1,
          bs = c("cc","ts")),family = "gaussian", data = .,
      knots=list(wind.dir.lag1=c(0,360)))

When no transformation is applied to RTRM, the Q-Q plot and histogram actually wind up looking decent, but the heteroscedasticity mentioned above is obvious and prominent.
  
I tried adding .05 across the board (which is negligible on the scale of my data) and log transforming my RTRM values, while keeping the model in the gaussian family. This fixes the heteroskedasticity issue, but the residuals get a little wonky. I know my data is not really poisson distributed, but the same thing happens with a square root transformation. These plots are from a model that is the same as above except the response is log(daily.rtrm+.05).
 
A log link in the gaussian family does not really fix either of these issues. The residuals stay heteroscedastic with a long right tail on the distribution.
If I switch to the tweedie family, both the log link and sqrt link (with daily.rtrm +.05 as the response) look good in terms of heteroscedasticity, but have left-skewed residual distributions. The skewness is not as bad as models with link functions in the gaussian family, however. Here are just the residual histograms so I don't further clog up this post with plots. The first one is from the family = tw(link = "log") model, and the second is from the family = tw(link = "sqrt") model.
 
After that, I don't really know where to go with this. Is there another distribution or link function I should be looking at, or do I settle for one that isn't perfect, but adequate?

Have you considered using only the difference in density between the two layers as the response and adding the density difference at 4ºC and 5ºC as an offset, for example? Perhaps modeling variance as well (?gaulss)?

Because the denominator of RTRM is constant, the difference in density is directly proportional to the RTRM so it shouldn't affect the distribution. I haven't heard of gaulss(), though, so I will check that out. thanks!
